# Asymptote: globally define latexmkrc

Tags: latexmk, asymptote

In section [7](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/LaTeX-usage.html#LaTeX-usage) of the Asymptote manual  is suggested that for a better use of the LaTeX integration via `latexmk` one need to put the file `latexmkrc` into the folder of its own `*.tex` file. However I was wandering if it was possible to define this command globally in `latexmk` avoiding to put the file `latexmkrc` every time it is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename your file `.latexmkrc` instead of `latexmkrc` and put it in your user home directory. For more options and more details, see the section "Configuration/Initialization (RC) Files" in [the latexmk manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf). (As of this writing, that section starts at the bottom of page 12.)